# Hash becomes array after post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash in Ruby:

```
params[:test]={:name=>'sharing'}
restPost(url, params)
```

on the other end, I output the params:

```
render :json=>{ :params=>params[:test] }
```

I get the result:

```
{"params":["name", "sharing"] }
```

It seems the hash is turned into a array. What I want is:

```
{"params": {"name":"sharing"}}
```

Comment: I assume this is for Rails and have tagged it as such; if not, please specify which web framework you are using.

Comment: what version of rails are u using? and what is the name of your controller

Comment: @Phrogz, it is ruby on rails. thanks.

Comment: @simonmenke, it is rails 3.1.1. the name is aspects_controller, but it should not matter? because I get the params.

Answer (score 2):

One way to deal with this might be to convert the array back to a Hash with `Hash[]`, e.g.:

```
a = ["name", "sharing"]
h = Hash[*a]
```